# Azure B2B application redirection to web app after login from the Invitation

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-active-directory, b2b, azure-ad-b2b

We are implementing an Azure B2B application that was given in the GitHub sample

https://github.com/Azure/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-b2bportal-web,

which was working as expected. After the redemption from the mail, the user was redirected to the b2b application(profile page), but we want to redirect to another web app(azure ad application) with Microsoft identity.

I tried to changes the redirect URLs of the b2b applications (Admin app and B2b pre-auth app) as mentioned in the above solution.

Can anyone suggest, how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the [B2B sample application](https://github.com/Azure/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-b2bportal-web), I see the inviteRedirectUrl (profile URL) in two places, where profile URL is mentioned in the code. Did you change in both the places?

- [SiteConfig.cs](https://github.com/Azure/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-b2bportal-web/blob/master/AzureB2BInvite/Models/SiteConfig.cs#L21)
- [PreApprovalController.cs](https://github.com/Azure/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-b2bportal-web/blob/master/B2BPortal/Areas/Admin/Controllers/PreApprovalController.cs#L81)

Comment: there is  a method GetProfileUrl in the Utils class of  B2BPortal.Common.Utils namespace